# Quickest and most efficient way to traverse an ArrayList in reverse

Tags: java, arraylist, iteration, micro-optimization

Is there a quicker, more efficient means of doing so than using a `ListIterator`?

```
ListIterator<Integer> itr = list.listIterator(list.size());
while(itr.hasPrevious()){
    System.out.println(itr.previous());
}
```

Comment: if list is not double linked, it is trivially faster to iterate from front to end... I am assuming this is not the case.

Comment: I'm assuming you need to iterate backwards.

Comment: @amit: It is an array list, there should be no difference here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depending on the implementation of the `List` and `ListIterator` the following may be (slightly) quicker.

```
List l;
for (int i = l.size()-1; i >=0; i--) {
    System.out.println(l.get(i));
}
```

This may be faster for an `ArrayList` but it will almost certainly be slower for a `LinkedList`.

Your best bet is to just use the iterator.

It is almost certain that whatever work you are doing in the loop will negate any performance gained by not using the iterator.

Comment: +1 for the last phrase, how is this faster than using an `Iterator`? Could you share a link?

Comment: @Alberto, I am just assuming that the iterator may add extra overhead that directly accessing the `List` would avoid.  But, I'm not 100% sure.  This is definitely a case of micro optimization.

Comment: @Alberto, anything which avoids creating an object is usually faster than one which creates an object. (Though the difference may be marginal)

Comment: @jjnguy, thanks! I ran timing tests and it seems that there is little-to-no difference between using an iterator and what you've suggested as an alternative. for me, using an iterator makes the code more readable.

Comment: @mre, that is what I would do.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, using a simple index-based for loop could be faster by a miniscule amount since there is no method call overhead for the test, but in practice this is very, very unlikely to be significant and may not actually manifest at all.

It's far more important that the iterator-based solution is clearer and works efficiently with linked lists, not just ArrayLists

Comment: What test are you talking about?

Comment: @Alberto: hasPrevious() vs. i>= 0 - and of course the iterator object itself has to be created.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the implementation class of the list, it may be more efficient to reverse the list (using `Collections.reverse`), use a forward iterator, and then reverse the list again to restore it.

Note that `java.util.LinkedList` is a *double*-linked list, so this strategy isn't necessary; using `hasPrevious` and `previous` is just as efficient as going in the forward direction. This is true, I think, of every stock List implementation in java.util.

Comment: @mre, Ted was saying that for some very specific implementations of the list, reversing it may be faster.

Answer (score 1):

The solution you presented is as fast as using a regular for with an index. If you wish to search for an even better solution, i suggest an implementation with LinkedList as i think that that is the quickest solution avaliable.

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse by one line that is

**Collections.reverse(list);**

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();

arrayList.add("A");
arrayList.add("B");

System.out.println("Before Reverse Order : " + arrayList);

Collections.reverse(arrayList);

System.out.println("After Reverse : " + arrayList);
```

**Output**

```
Before Reverse Order : [A, B]
After Reverse : [B, A]
```